Problem with counting Battleship sunken ships/ships (Java)
So I am making a method for a battleship game which consists of ships ranging from 2-5 squares horizontally on a 10x10 grid in Java. This method is to count the number of sunken ships on the grid which are ships with all "*", a ship will be marked with "S" and water ".". I have made the method but I keep running into a problem when counting the number of sunken ships properly as it either counts one star sunken ships (which aren't valid ships) on a row as a sunken ship but recently I have run into the problem where it is counting all individual stars as a sunken ships. As you can see in the board below it is supposed to return 1 ship as that is the only valid one on the board but it is returning 4 when I run this method. This is also the issue later in the method for counting how many ships there aren't on the board/grid.
Here is the board/grid:
 static char[][] board = {
            {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
            {'.', '.', 'S', '.', '.', '*', '*', '.', '.', '.'},
            {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
            {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
            {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
            {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '*', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
            {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '*', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
            {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
            {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
            {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'}
        };

public static int sunkenShips(char boardArray[][]) {
        board = boardArray;
        int sunkenShips = 0; //counts the amount of sunken ships
        boolean sunken = false; //used later to check if the the space is a sunken ship
        for(char[] row : boardArray) { //loops through board array
            for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) { //loops through each row
                if(row[i] == '*') { //checks if current element is a sunken ship
                    sunken = true; //sets it to true then
                    int ii = 0; //resets so it can check if it is a one star (not a sunken ship) in each row 
                    for(int j = i; j < row.length && j < i + 5; j++) { //if it is sunken it checks whether its a valid sunken ship (2-5 squares long), it will go on until the 5th square and/or until the end of the row 
                        ii++;
                        if(row[j] != '*' && ii == 1) { //checks if the next square after the one is was on is a * and if not which would make it only 1 star and not a sunken ship, break out of the loop
                            sunken = false; //changes it to false therefore
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(sunken == true) { //if the ship is sunken then increments to the sunken ship variable
                        sunkenShips++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (validBoard(boardArray) == 12 && sunken == true) { //checks if board is valid using other method and if board has sunken ships
            return sunkenShips;
        }
        else if (validBoard(boardArray)==12) {
            for(char[] row: boardArray) {
                for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) { //goes through the array to check if there aren't any ships
                        if (row[i] == 'S') { //checks if there is a ship
                            boolean validShip = true; //used to checking if its a valid ship (2-5 squares in length)
                            int iii = 0; //resets so it can check if it is a one S (not a ship) in each row 
                        for(int j = i; j < row.length && j < i + 5; j++) { // same logic as above
                            iii++;
                            if(row[j] != 'S' && iii == 1) { //same logic as above to check if its a ship
                                validShip = false;
                                break;
                            } else {
                                validShip = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (validShip == false) { // if there aren't ships it should return this value
                            return 0;
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
        return 2; //default return value
    }

I tried a lot tweaking with this part of the code iterates through the next 4 spaces to check if its a valid battle ship and a checking if statement to check if its a valid or not (minimum 2 spaces long). But every time it either doesn't run through the if statement or recently not go through the for loop properly.
for(int j = i; j < row.length && j < i + 5; j++) { //if it is sunken it checks whether its a valid sunken ship (2-5 squares long), it will go on until the 5th square and/or until the end of the row 
                        ii++;
                        if(row[j] != '*' && ii == 1) { //checks if the next square after the one is was on is a * and if not which would make it only 1 star and not a sunken ship, break out of the loop
                            sunken = false; //changes it to false therefore
                            break;
                        }
                    }

Here is the question for this method for anyone wondering:

Write a method that when given a valid board (see above – assume the
input board is valid) returns the number of sunk ships. If there are
no ships on the board (this is still a valid board) a value should be
returned.


If a ship is required to be more than one unit long, then your board is not valid.  Your S is only one unit.

You might consider a function that takes an X,Y coordinate and answers the question "how many stars are there to the right of this square?" and another "how many stars are there below this square?".  Then, remember to mark those as "seen" so you don't count them again.

@TimRoberts the one unit ship was there for testing if the second part of the method worked, also would a X,Y coordinate function be built in?

@Danish one-unit ship is not really a good test case. There's a reason why the real battleship's game smallest ship was two units long.

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but I think you need to store your ships as tuples. The way I see it, each ship has at least three attributes: 1) ID, 2) length, and 3) orientation (V or H).  When you position your ship on the board, it should show the ID instead of just an "S." On a hit, there should be a function that will go to the data structure that contains your tuples. The information in the tuple should help your game determine when your ship is sunken or not. And, as I type this, maybe the orientation is not needed.

In my opinion, the description is not detailed enough on what constitutes a sunken ship! How many ships are sunk in this row? {'*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '.', '.', '.', '.'} Is it 3 two-lengths ships? Is it 2 three-length ships? Is at a combination of 1 two-length ship followed by 1 three-length ship (or that combo reversed)? Is it 1 two-length ship followed by 1 four-length ship (or that combo reversed)? Or is it just 1 five-length ship? There are lots of combinations like this...

@Idle_Mind this is why you should store the coordinates of a given ship in a map (see my answer). A sunken ship is one that, when given the coordinates (key) of a given ship (value) that was previously hit, the map returns zero keys for that value. If I was to guess, this is how Electronic Battleship works. For every ship, you have to enter the coordinates until all your ships are entered. You could even flip the data structure and have a map of <Ship, Coordinates>, but I honestly think the opposite <Coordinate, Ship> is simpler.

@hfontanez I agree with you, but based on the simplicity of the description, this is probably just an ACADEMIC / HW problem to be solved. What you're doing makes sense, but is way too complicated for someone just learning to program...

@Idle_Mind Yes indeed it is

Note the description specifically stated that ships are oriented horizontally, so we don't need to worry about vertical ships.
From my comment above:

In my opinion, the description is not detailed enough on what
constitutes a sunken ship! How many ships are sunk in this row? {'*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '.', '.', '.', '.'} Is it 3 two-lengths
ships? Is it 2 three-length ships? Is at a combination of 1 two-length
ship followed by 1 three-length ship (or that combo reversed)? Is it 1
two-length ship followed by 1 four-length ship (or that combo
reversed)? Or is it just 1 five-length ship? There are lots of
combinations like this...

If we assume that all sunken ships are left-aligned in a streak, and it is safe to always take the longest possible ship in a streak, then here is a simple answer:
  public static int sunkenShips(char boardArray[][]) {
    int streak;
    int sunkShips = 0;
    for(char[] row : board) {
      streak = 0;
      for(char mark : row) {
        if (mark == '*') {
          streak++;
          // max length hit; reset in case ships are up against each other
          if (streak == 5) {
            sunkShips++;
            streak = 0;
          }
        }
        else {
          if (streak >=2) {
            sunkShips++;  
          }
          streak = 0;
        }
      }
      // Needed if the ship is against the right edge:
      if (streak >= 2) {
        sunkShips++;  
      }
    }
    return sunkShips;
  }

All we're doing is increasing the streak count whenever we encounter a *. If we hit the longest ship length of 5 then we increase the sunken ship count and start the current streak count back over at zero. Any time we hit a character that is not a *, we see if the current streak was at least two length long and increase the ship count accordingly, followed by resetting the current streak count back to zero.
Lastly, if the ship is against the right edge of the board, then we would not have hit a non * character signally a need for a check of a minimum two length ship so we perform one last check.

Hi thanks for the answer, to clarify the ships aren't places adjacent to each other horizontally and there are not vertical ships. Your answer relies heavily on whether the ships are touching which they aren't. I am just stuck with sunken ships not being counted properly even with the if statement checker.

It doesn't "rely heavily" on whether the ships are touching. It simply handles that case as well.  It'll find ships that are not touching just fine!  Have you tried it out?...

Apologies I didn't read it properly the first time round but yes I have tried it now and it now works, thank you very much!

Indeed you should have a 10x10 grid for your game. However, I see it a bit different:
static char[][] board = {
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
    {'.', '.', '1', '.', '.', '*', '*', '.', '.', '.'},
    {'.', '.', '1', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
    {'.', '.', '.', '2', '2', '2', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '*', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '*', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'}
};

Since Java does not have the concept of "tuple," create a Java record. (If using Java 15 or earlier, just create a POJO)
public record Ship (int id, int length, char orientation)

Somewhere in the application, you should store the tuples. Probably a Map<int[], Ship>. I haven't thought this through. This wasn't meant to be THE answer. It is meant more than a more complete comment than what I could have posted in your question's comment section. That said, I think "my comment" has sufficient technical details to be AN answer of sorts.
When you play the game, and onHit(), you can look up the (x,y) key in the map, and get the Ship (tuple). The onHit() method should be able to determine the matching ID from that coordinate (validation), replace the ID in the grid with maybe an 'x', and determine whether or not the ship is sunken or not. For that, the tuple will provide the orientation, so that you can look up adjacent positions in the grid IN THAT DIRECTION (up and down for "V", and side to side for "H"). If it finds more ID values, the ship is not sunk, and the game goes on. IF ship is sunk, the method should remove that entry from the map.
EDIT: For the case of ship #1, you can have these entries on the map:
Ship ship1 = new Ship(1, 2, 'V');
...
Map(int[], Ship) player1Pieces = new Map<>();
player1Pieces.put([1, 2], ship1);
player1Pieces.put([2, 2], ship1);

When a hit is scored, simply pop the entry from the map. Eventually, all the entries for a ship will be popped. You may be able to simplify your search by creating a lambda that will search for remaining values containing the same ship object. If none are found after the pop, you have sunken that ship. In this case, you won't even need the orientation parameter in your tuple.
One last thing, since a given coordinate cannot be shared between two ships, it makes this array a perfect key for your game piece map. Also remember that if you pass to a map coordinates (key) that don't exist in the map, the map will return null. So your code can use this to determine what is a miss and what is a hit.
public void move(Player player, int[] coordinates) {
    int playerId = player.getId();
    switch(playerId) {

        case 1:
            Ship ship = player2Pieces.get(coordinates);
            if(ship == null) {
                System.out.println("Missed!");
            } else {
                // TODO Pop the map
                // Determine if it's just a hit, or the ship has sunk
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            // TODO Same logic as case 1 for the other player
            break;
    }
}


To get the number of sunken ships, you could also write a lambda function that will give you the count of unique Ship values in the map. To determine whether the game board itself is valid or not, all you need to do is write a function that

Validate the entire grid for valid characters (., *, int value 1-10, better yet, 0-9)
There should be at least 2 ships in the board and no more than 10. One ship represents that the game is over and one of the players won. I think in that case, you should return that the board is invalid so that a new game could be started.

To see if each position in the grid is valid, you can brute-force iterate the grid and if a valid character is found, continue iterating until all positions are validated OR an invalid character is found. Keep track of the ship ID numbers encountered. Once that is done, Examine the ship count. Return 1 < shipCount < 11
EDIT #2: If you do the above, you need a special validation for new game start. For new game, you need to (perhaps blindly) reset your board to contain only dots. Something like this should work:
boolean quitGame = false;
boolean validBoard = false;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(!quitGame)
        if (!validBoard) {
            reset(); // creates board and sets valid flag to true
        }
        playGame(...); // When a round is over, valid flag should be set to false by the conditions I previously outlined
    }
}

You also need to figure out how to account for adjacent ships with the same orientation.
    {'.', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '.', '.', '.', '.'},

IF after some turns, you end up like this:
    {'.', '1', '*', '*', '2', '2', '.', '.', '.', '.'},

Have you sunk ship #1? I think if you follow my original map idea, this will be easy to determine because there will still be an entry on the map with the last coordinate of ship #1. So, your function of counting the number of coordinates for a given ship will still work.

Hi thanks for the answer, your solution to this problem is a bit out of my reach of what I can do as I am still learning programming in Java and as a whole. I asked the question originally so I could find the solution to what was causing the issue in the method which is only part of the battleship game which I am doing not the whole one. But your answer will definitely come in handy when I get to doing the whole game.

@Danish Got it. But if I may, just remember this as a takeaway. This is a good problem to revisit when you learn Data Structures. As the name suggests, it is how you structure your data. This problem seems to be perfect for the use of Maps to store your data in Java. In other languages, it would be a tuple as I mentioned before.

@Danish check out this prototype of Battle Ship game based on the idea I shared with you. Feel free to download from my github and try it at home. https://github.com/prof-fontanez/BattleShip. When you do, let me know what you think.
